# SlidingDrawer with no handle?

Tags: android, handle, slidingdrawer

Consider the [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) in Android. All samples I've seen have a large button as a handle. Cool. But, I want an invisible handle, just like the one in the Android main window!

Whenever I drag from the bottom of my view, the slider should come up (I want it to slide from bottom to top). And no handle should ever be drawn!

How can this be accomplished in Android 2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick. I set the `SlidingDrawer` handle to the following `View`:

```
 <View
            android:id="@id/handle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dip" />
```

Comment: this will makes the handle height to 3dip. but how set the touch or drag events to content view to make the slider work? please update if there is any possible way.

Comment: I gave up on that. My sliding drawer now looks like the 2.1 "notification" slider :)